# vanilla ubuntu-vm-builder on i7 aborts aborts (with PAE?)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

host: intel i7-4* cpu, running linux kubuntu 14.04

guest: attempting to create.

```
ubuntu-vm-builder kvm saucy
```

eventually,

```
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic amd64 3.11.0-19.33 [14.5 MB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main linux-image-virtual amd64 3.11.0.19.20 [2302 B]
Fetched 14.5 MB in 6s (2335 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic.
(Reading database ... 10289 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic (from .../linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic_3.11.0-19.33_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-virtual.
Unpacking linux-image-virtual (from .../linux-image-virtual_3.11.0.19.20_amd64.deb) ...
, stderr: grep: /proc/cpuinfo: No such file or directory
This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic_3.11.0-19.33_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.11.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.11.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic_3.11.0-19.33_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

isn't this supposed to work??  an i7 does have PAE.  a grep on pae in /proc/cpuinfo confirms it.  and

and

```
 kvm-ok
  INFO: /dev/kvm exists
  KVM acceleration can be used
```

does anyone know what is going on here?

/iaw

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your PAE CPU being treated like a non-PAGE CPU. However, we had the same error message, *This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU*, and this worked for us:

---

#### Kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU install KVM guest on Ubuntu 13.10 – Fix

...

Basically, you just need to ensure that the linux-image-generic package (i.e. a kernel which supports non-PAE CPU’s) is installed by setting the addpkg flag like so:

`--addpkg=linux-image-generic`

[Source: randomhacks.co.uk](http://www.randomhacks.co.uk/kernel-does-not-support-a-non-pae-cpu-install-kvm-guest-on-ubuntu-13-10-fix/)

---